JavaFX Agregar Font mediante css
Tengo un codigo en JavaFX en el cual quiero agregar una fuente mediante el css en el cual mediante la documentación me dice que puedo hacerlo de la siguiente manera en el archivo css, el cual ya lo tengo cargado en mi proyecto ya que si puedo aplicar estilos mediante las etiqueta "-fx-"
@font-face{
    font-family: "webdings";    
    src: url(../font/webdings.ttf);     
}

.root{    
    -fx-background-color: #5E0000; 
}


#lblClose{
    -fx-font-family: "webdings";
    -fx-font-size: 20;   
} 

El archivo css lo cargo en mi clase principal de esta manera
//Creando rectangulo para bordes redondeados
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(300, 250);
        rect.setArcHeight(20.0);
        rect.setArcWidth(20.0);
        
        //Quitando los bordes incluyendo la barra de titulo
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);   
        
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/viewExample.fxml"));
        root.setClip(rect);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(JavaFXToggleSwitch_01.class.getResource("/css/style.css").toExternalForm()); 
        
        stage.setScene(scene);                           
        stage.show();

Y mi archivo .fxml esto resumido ya que solo quiero aplicar la fuente al label
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" accessibleRole="IMAGE_VIEW" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="300.0" stylesheets="@../css/style.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.viewExampleController">
    <children>
        <Pane fx:id="barraTitulo" nodeOrientation="RIGHT_TO_LEFT" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
        </Pane>
      <Label fx:id="lblClose" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="250.0" layoutY="35.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="79.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;" text="TEST" textAlignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="220.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">         
      </Label>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>

y no se aplica la fuente, entonces lo que hice fue aplicarlo mediante las fuentes del sistema de esta manera omitiendo el @font-face y si se aplica
@font-face{
    font-family: "webdings";    
    src: url(../font/webdings.ttf);     
}

.root{    
    -fx-background-color: #5E0000; 
}


#lblClose{
    -fx-font-family: "Arial";
    -fx-font-size: 20;   
} 

pero entonces al no poder aplicar la fuente mediante el css lo hice mediante java de esta manera
lblClose.setFont(Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/font/webdings.ttf"),20));

y asi si funciono y se aplico la fuente, pero me gustaria saber el porque no pude de la otra manera o en que estoy mal

Te dejo 2 referencias para que las revises, pero recuerda que si estas usando una fuente que no es predeterminada entonces tienes que cargarla
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-a-text-in-javafx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173288/specifying-external-font-in-javafx-css/12181948#12181948
